# Error: ToolTip Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on tooltip prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this is an old issue but still I tried a lot with answer provided which didn't work for me.

I tried jquery-ui to load first later with bootstarp to load which gave me new set of issues.

onclicking of the tooltip for 2 to 3 times I am seeing this error

here is my code for onclick:

```js
local._toggleClosing = function(el, close) {

  var onClickHandler = function(event) {
    el.tooltip("close");
  };

  close ? el.on("click.tooltip", onClickHandler) :
    el.off("click.tooltip");
};
```

Comment: Can you make a working example that shows the issue? Then we can help you.

Comment: difficult for me to post the whole code